# Importing libsodium-wrappers in JEST throws the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sodium')"

Tags: jestjs, libsodium

I'm importing libsodium-wrappers in JEST and it throws the error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sodium')
```

The code that throws the error is

```
import _sodium from "libsodium-wrappers";
```

And the stack trace goes to this line

```
(var t = "object" == typeof e.sodium && "function" == typeof e.sodium.onload ? e.sodium.onload : null;)
```

e is undefined in Jest